# Why doesn't PageComponent respect the right contentInset

Tags: framerjs

This is taken (almost) verbatim from [PageComponent](http://framerjs.com/examples/preview/#pages-simple.framer#code) example (minus the imported Sketch doc), yet in my code, the right `contentInset` is totally ignored and the cards are offset strangely on each card after the first.

```
# Set-up PageComponent
page = new PageComponent
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    y: 0
    scrollVertical: false
    contentInset: {top: 32, left: 32, right: 32}
    backgroundColor: "pink"

# Variable that adjusts the amount of cards
amount = 4
print page.width
print screen.width
# Create and style the cards within a loop
for i in [0...amount]
    card = new Layer 
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
        borderRadius: 8
        width: page.width - 64
        height: 1040 
        x: page.width * i
        superLayer: page.content
    card.style.boxShadow = "0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
```

I'm using Framer Studio ver 1.13.25 (1583)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in one of the latest versions of the framerjs library.
You can overpass the bug by putting every page inside a full width wrapper.

Check here a fixed example: http://share.framerjs.com/z09x27iqjce1/​

I hope it helps :)